# What is maven and jenkins with selenium?

Tags: selenium, java

What is the exact importance of using maven and jenkins ?
Can you tell me the advantages of using maven and jenkins in my project ?

Comment: advantages compared to what?

Comment: @Testeasy  compared to page object model design pattern

Comment: I don't really see the comparision between POM and Maven/Jenkins? Former is a design pattern , the later are tools.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Jenkins is continues integration server and this is open source.
Maven is Build manage server for Java based projects and it is also open source.

So if you are dealing with a big java project with critical releases and nightly builds then its better to use both technologys.

Answer (score 2):

Maven is project management tool. Maven makes life of a java developer little bit easier. Maven manages dependency very efficiently. You don't need to  download jar files ( selenium, TestNG and other jars ) manually, just need to put few lines of XML in POM.xml and save it. Maven will download all dependency automatically from it's online repository. Using Maven, you can clean and build your work space. Better to have some Hands on experience.

Jenkins is a continuations integration tool. If you want to run your test automatically on code checking or at any time in a day, you can use Jenkins. A freestyle job can be created very easily in Jenkins and run test automatically.

This is just a overview of both Maven and Jenkins. It's better to try both to get some real time experience and believe me , you will never regret.

Comment: @log_file  Can you tell me about the git hub and jenkins? Is it better for using in jenkins in git hub ?

Comment: Hi, GitHub is just code repository. However it is widely accepted to use GitHub in Jenkins. It is depend on your development and setup.